# É possível fazer este efeito com CSS?

Tags: css, imagem, animate

Com efeito demonstrado no vídeo abaixo `Sony Spherize` faz parecer como se o personagem da foto estivesse "respirando", existe alguma forma de fazer igual, ou simular algo parecido com CSS?

[image: Efeito]

Link para o vídeo:

https://youtu.be/e-jWOFOGgwM

Ou o mais correto seria criar um GIF da animação do vídeo e colocar no HTML?

**Obs:** No vídeo está um pouco exagerado o efeito, mas acredito que dê pra entender sobre o que estou falando.

Abaixo a imagem que sofre o efeito simulando a "respiração" no vídeo

[image: Personagem Goku]

Comment: Acho  dificíl fazer dessa maneira, uma forma parecida seria deixa-la diminuindo e aumentando levemente. Outra forma não conheço...

Comment: Não manjo muito de HTML e CSS, você pode usar a <a href="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp">tag map</a> e juntamente algum transform no css.

Comment: É possível usar isso para mapear as áreas da imagem onde eu posso aplicar uma animação scale?

Comment: @LeoLetto acredito que sim,  nunca etste.

Answer (score 9):

Em princípio, não tem muito o que fazer com CSS neste caso, e provavelmente seria melhor uma animação ou vídeo *embedded*.

Pra não ficar completamente sem solução, montei um exemplo de manipulação de imagem com JS e Canvas:

```js
function distorce(idOriginal, idDistorcido, porcentagem) {
    var original = document.getElementById(idOriginal);
    var ctx = original.getContext('2d');
    var pxO= ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    var distorcido = document.getElementById(idDistorcido);
    var ctx = distorcido.getContext('2d');
    var pxD = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    for(var y = 0; y < original.height; y++) {
        for(var x = 0; x < original.width; x++) {
            var cx = x-original.width/2;
            var cy = y-original.height/2;
            var r = Math.sqrt(cx*cx+cy*cy);
            var maxr = Math.min(original.width,original.height)/2;
            if (r>maxr) {
                var dx = x;
                var dy = y;
            } else {
                var a = Math.atan2(cx,cy);
                var k = (r/maxr)*(r/maxr)*porcentagem/200+(200-porcentagem)/200;
                var dx = Math.floor(Math.cos(a)*r*k+maxr);
                var dy = Math.floor(Math.sin(a)*r*k+maxr);
            }
            pxD.data[(x+y*original.width)*4  ] = pxO.data[(dx+dy*original.width)*4  ];
            pxD.data[(x+y*original.width)*4+1] = pxO.data[(dx+dy*original.width)*4+1];
            pxD.data[(x+y*original.width)*4+2] = pxO.data[(dx+dy*original.width)*4+2];
            pxD.data[(x+y*original.width)*4+3] = pxO.data[(dx+dy*original.width)*4+3];  
        }
    }
    ctx.putImageData(pxD, 0, 0);
}
```

Aproveitei um pouco da fórmula [deste endereço](http://splashnology.com/article/pixel-distortions-with-bilinear-filtration-in-html5-canvas/4739/), mas praticamente refiz o resto de forma à função ficar "regulável" por um parâmetro.

Vale notar que é uma prova de conceito, e que para animação, este tipo de distorção é um bocado custoso para justificar seu uso.

Teste "ao vivo" no **[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/bacco/pen/LbaQmg)**.

Answer (score 2):

Bom, não sei como distorcer e nem se é possivel, mas o mais proximo que cheguei foi disso:

```css
.img{ height:320px; animation: 3s movimenta infinite;}
@keyframes movimenta{
0%{ height:320px}
50%{ height:360px}
 100%{ height:320px}
}
```

```html
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/oXf2YdI.png" class="img">
```

Espero que isso ajude em algo!!

Comment: Então, eu estava pensando em fazer algo com o transform scale,  se possível fazer o scale só no centro, ainda não testei pois estou esperando pra ver se tem algo mais apropriado.